# How to update a library from a website?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, updates, libraries

I'm running Ubuntu 16 and i want to install libsodium library.

here's what i have tried:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libsodium
```

but the libsodium they have is outdated when i do `apt-get`.

they have the latest libsodium here: https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/

it is called "LATEST.tar.gz". sorry im new to this but how do i install libsodium from the new source rather than the old one from `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is available [here](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/installation/)

Simplifying the steps:

1. `$ tar -xvzf LATEST.tar.gz -C ~/libsodium`
2. `$ cd ~/libsodium`
3. `$ ./configure`
4. `$ make && make check`
5. `$ sudo make install`

I'd recommend you read the documentation thoroughly.  There may be a reason that the last known compiled version of `libsodium` for 16.04 was `1.0.8`.

Searching PPA's I found only one PPA ([here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsodium)) with the current version of `1.0.11`, and that was only for Ubuntu Yakkety and later.